# Preprocessor symbol for Net without platform

Tags: c#, .net-5, preprocessor-directive, .net-6.0

I'm working with Xamarin/MAUI prjects.

Previously if I wanted to do a preprocessor check for platform-independant code, I could do `#if NETSTANDARD`.

Now, I'm not sure. I have a project that targets `net6.0;net6.0-android;net6.0-ios`.

What symbol can I use that check for `net6.0` (without any platform). Both `NET` and `NET6_0` are defined in `net6.0-android;net6.0-ios` as well.

PS: Here's the [list of all symbols](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/includes/preprocessor-symbols.md)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-a-target-framework "When using a symbol that represents a .NET Standard, .NET Core, *or .NET 5 TFM*, replace dots and hyphens with an underscore and change lowercase letters to uppercase" so `#if !NET6_0_ANDROID_OR_GREATER && !NET6_0_IOS_OR_GREATER` ?

Comment: Of course, you haven't explained *Why* you want to test "for platform-independant code". Can you give an example?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman `#if NOT_ANY_OTHER_POSSIBLE_PLATFORM` is not what I'm looking for. This way, I would need to change those `if`s if my targets change (or define my own symbol, and use that, but I was wondering whether there's a OOTB one)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Context is not really needed here, but sure. I'm working on support for `.net6` target in MauiCompat, and this (https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat-1.3.0/src/CommunityToolkit/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat/Views/DrawingView/Service/DrawingViewService.shared.cs#L9) needs to be migrated.

Comment: I was helped by this tip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74279813/why-would-net6-0-windows-be-undefined-in-a-net6-0-windows-project

Answer (score 3):

Recommend use the `SupportedOSPlatform` attribute where applicable. e.g., `[SupportedOSPlatform("android")]`

Thus, you will self-comment all your platform-dependent code and all other code is known to be platform independent. If you change supported targets, simply change the project:

```
<SupportedPlatform Include="android" />
<SupportedPlatform Include="ios" />
...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/platform-compat-analyzer